# Displaying answers on ranking question in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, ranking, survey

I have the following variables which are the result of one ranking question. On that question, participants got the 7 listed motivations presented and should rank them. Here, value 1 means the participant put the motivation on position 1, and value 7 means he put it on last position. The ranking is expressed through the numbers on these variables (numbers 1 to 7):

```
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ id                       : num  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
 $ motivation_quantity      : num  NA 3 1 NA 3 NA NA NA 1 NA ...
 $ motivation_quality       : num  NA 1 6 NA 3 NA NA NA 3 NA ...
 $ motivation_timesaving    : num  NA 6 4 NA 2 NA NA NA 5 NA ...
 $ motivation_contribution  : num  NA 4 2 NA 1 NA NA NA 2 NA ...
 $ motivation_alternativelms: num  NA 5 3 NA 6 NA NA NA 7 NA ...
 $ motivation_inspiration   : num  NA 2 7 NA 4 NA NA NA 4 NA ...
 $ motivation_budget        : num  NA 7 5 NA 7 NA NA NA 6 NA ...
```

What I want to do now is to calculate and visualize the results on the ranking question (i.e. visualizing the results on the motivations). Since I havent worked with R for a long time, I am not sure how to best do this.

One way I could imagine is to first calculate the top 3 answers (which are the motivations which were most frequently ranked on position "1", "2", and "3" across participants.
Would really appreciate it if someone could help out with doing this or even show a better way how to analyse and visualize my data.

I originally had an visualization in microsoft forms but this one got destroyed by a bug overnight. It looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These variables are defined by RStudio as numeric (in statistics terms it refers to continuous variables). The goal is then to convert them into categorical variables (called factors in RStudio).

Let's get to work :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# lets us first convert the id column into integers so we can apply mutate_if on the other numeric factors and convert all of them into factors (categorical variables), we shall name your dataframe (df)

df$id <- as.integer(df$id)


# and now let's apply mutate_if to convert all the other variables (numeric) into factors (categorical variables).

df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,factor,
                     levels = 1:7)

# I guess in your case that would be all, but if you wanted the content of the dataframe to be position_1, position_2 ...position_7, we just add labels like this :

df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,factor,
                     levels = 1:7,
                     labels = paste(rep("position",7),1:7,sep="_"))


# For the visualisation now, we need to use the function gather in order to convert the df dataframe into a two column dataframe (and keeping the id column), we shall name this new dataframe df1

df1 <- df %>% gather(key=Questions, value=Answers, motivation_quantity:motivation_budget,-id  )


# the df1 dataframe now includes three columns : the id column - the Questions columns - the Answers column. 
# we can now apply the ggplot function on the new dataframe for the visualisation

# first the colours

colours <- c("firebrick4","firebrick3", "firebrick1", "gray70", "blue", "blue3" ,"darkblue") 


# ATTENTION since there are NAs in your dataframe, either you can recode them as zeros or delete them (for the visualisation) using the subset function within the ggplot function as follows :

ggplot(subset(df1,!is.na(Answers)))+
  aes(x=Questions,fill=Answers)+
  geom_bar()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours) + 
  ylab("position_levels")

# of course you can enter many modifications into the visualisation but in total I think that's what you need.
```